# Lotusscript generate random 8 characters string?

Tags: random, lotus-notes, lotusscript

How do I generate a string of 8 characters using lotusscript in this pattern? Eg: 0E 1F A3 ZK (there are spaces after every 2 characters including the last). Each character can only be either 0-9 or A-Z (uppercased only). I've used the `Randomize` and `Rnd` method before and thinking of applying it here but I'm not sure if that's the correct way and how to achieve that. Another thing is this string is going to be saved into my document and I have a view that list each of the generated string. Which means each time a string is generated, it has to be unique. If the string generated is already used in another document, then continue generating until one that hasn't been used is generated.

Comment: Why not just use @Unique to get a random string? There must be a specific need for this 2x4 format, eh?

Comment: @DavidNavarre I'm doing something that has to do with smartcard which for testing purpose I don't have enough unique smartcard for each document. Therefore this is the closest I could get to make the test data at least look like real data. (The Card ID is in the 2x4 format)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Rnd` in this case too.

Define a function `getRandom()` which gives you a random string in format "XX XX XX XX" with every call.

```ls
Function getRandom() As String
    Const charList = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    getRandom = _
    Mid(charList, 35*Rnd+1, 1) + Mid(charList, 35*Rnd+1, 1) + " " + _
    Mid(charList, 35*Rnd+1, 1) + Mid(charList, 35*Rnd+1, 1) + " " + _
    Mid(charList, 35*Rnd+1, 1) + Mid(charList, 35*Rnd+1, 1) + " " + _
    Mid(charList, 35*Rnd+1, 1) + Mid(charList, 35*Rnd+1, 1)
End Function
```

- `charList` is a string with all allowed characters 0-9 and A-Z.
- you get an random number between 1 and 36 with `35*Rnd+1`. This is your index in `charList` to get randomly one of the characters.

Call the function `getRandom()` in a cycle as long as you get a string which is not yet in your view.

Comment: I'd suggest to use randomize to seed the random number generated as suggested in Help. Otherwise you might get the same random strings again and again...

Comment: Of course, if people are working on different replicas or many people simultaneously, you may end up getting duplicates anyway, since they wouldn't be in the view at the time the system checks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sID = Join(Evaluate(|@Password(@Unique)|))

Mid$(sID, 2, 2) & " " & Mid$(sID, 4, 2) & " " & Mid$(sID, 6, 2) & " " & Mid$(sID, 8, 2)
```

How it works:

1. @Unique is a sequential string token
2. @Password(anyText) will return a unique 32 digit HEX string enclosed in parenthesis
3. Evaluate will run the @Function formula and return an array of 1 element. So the Join around the Evaluate will turn that to a string scalar value.
4. The Mid$ functions simply yield 2 character values at 2 character offsets.

The only issue regarding your original parameters of your question is that you will never see get values above F since we are using Hexadecimal characters (0-9, A-F)